# Can I get my rank on Stack Overflow according to the technology (.NET) I work on and country I live?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way to filter all .NET developers from India, and see my rank on it?

If I can see more details like top 5 Indian .NET developers.

Can this be implemented as a feature on the Stack Overflow home page/dashboard for everyone?

Comment: Very few people put in a location so knowing who the Indian developers are is not really possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tl;dr: No, and no.

As Robert Longson mentioned, most people do not put in their location. The best way to filter *everybody* by location is to use a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query to find all users who have "India", "Mumbai", "West Bengal", etc. in their location field. However, this will miss everyone in India who didn't enter a location, or entered some obscure city name, or made a typo when entering their location, or... you get the idea.

Filtering by only .NET developers is nearly impossible. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net/topusers lists people who have gained the most upvotes from answers on questions that are tagged with [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net). However, many of those people aren't .NET devs. Lots of them may have gained upvotes in [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) by answering questions that are *related to*, but not *about*, .NET.

The closest you can get to what you want is to make a SEDE query that ranks all people using an algorithm of your choosing, and then manually filtering them by whether they have an Indian-looking location, name, or picture. However, you will get a lot of people that aren't .NET developers, but have answered a lot of questions that happen to be tagged with [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net); and people that have an Indian-looking name or picture, but don't live in India. You will also miss a lot of people who are .NET developers, but aren't active in [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net); and people that live in India, but don't have an Indian-looking name, location, or picture.

Comment: You can always try a [language based filter](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22valuable+answer%22+is%3Aq).